# Como selecionar uma ul específica com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
    $('.menu-expand').click(function () {
       $(this).find('ul').toggleClass("menu-mobile-expandido");
    });
```

Gostaria de selecionar não qualquer `ul`, mas a primeira `ul` dentro da classe `.menu-expand`.

Tentei utilizar `.menu-expand > ul` dentro do find mas não funcionou.

Comment: `$(this).find('ul:first')` não resolve o problema? ou simplemente  `$('ul.menu-expand:first')`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o método `first()` do JQuery onde este retornará o primeiro elemento da coleção.

```
$('.menu-expand').click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').first().toggleClass("menu-mobile-expandido");
});
```

> **Vide documentação:** [first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/)

Answer (score 0):

Existe no seletor de css o `:first-child`

Você poderia utilizá-lo assim:

```
$('.menu-expand').click(function () {
   $('.menu-expand ul:first-child').toggleClass("menu-mobile-expandido");
});
```

A ideia pe selecionar o primeiro filho `ul` dentro do .menu-expand

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira bem prática de fazer isso é utilizando o seletor [:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/#eq-index), com ele você não fica preso ao primeiro elemento, pode colocar qualquer número ali, deixando o código bem mais flexível, até para ser utilizado com um `for` por exemplo.

```js
$('.menu-expand').on('click', function () {
   $('.menu-expand:eq(0)').css('color','red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul >
  <li class="menu-expand">UM</li>
  <li class="menu-expand">DOIS</li>
  <li class="menu-expand">TRÊS</li>
</ul>
```